# Can I install a signal handler in a seperate function

Tags: c, signals, systems-programming

I realize this is kind of a silly question that I'm pretty sure I will be able to. But, if I were to install a signal handler in a function other than main, is it safe to assume the signal handler will remain after returning from the method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in a separate function, `signal()` does not *have* to be done in the `main()` function, it can be done anywhere in the call stack.

The call to `signal()` associates a signal number to an action, and the action may be a function address. There is no transient information (like stack variables or dynamic memory) that needs to be kept around after the association.